# How much can I deduct for moving expenses

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

I moved this year for work. I qualify for a moving expenses deduction but I'm not sure how much of the expense is deductible.

I flew to my new location with my parents on a Tuesday.  We rented a car for 2 days to get around and stayed in a hotel while I looked for an apartment.  I signed a lease on Friday but stayed at the hotel until Monday since I didn't have a bed at the apartment until Monday.  My parents flew back home on Friday.

I'm assuming I can deduct the following: The cost of my flight (not including my parents), the cost of the rental car and the cost of the hotel from Tuesday to Friday.  Is this correct?  Or am I deducting too much/too little?

IRS publication 521 says: `The day of arrival is the day you secure lodging at the new place of residence, even if the lodging is on a temporary basis.`  I don't know if the hotel counts as 'temporary lodging' or not, so I don't know if anything beyond the plane ticket is deductible.

Comment: A hotel is a perfect example of temporary lodging. You are, quite literally, lodged there temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

The hotel is what they mean by "temporary basis". Only the flight is deductible, and only for you, not the parents.